# postgres: Why does SELECT NULL <> '' return FALSE?

Tags: postgresql, null

I recently was running a query on a data column that contained strings, empty strings and nulls.
I wanted to keep everything but the empty strings so naturally I did something like

```
WHERE my_row <> ''
```

However I discovered that this also removed my nulls. :(

I did a little poking around and found

```
SELECT NULL = ''  -- Returns False. No surprise here
```

But

```
SELECT NULL <> ''  -- Also returns False. Huh?
```

Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out whenever you do a standard comparison operator against a NULL, you get FALSE, NOT TRUE or NULL back.

If you want to do comparisons on a column that has NULL in it, you can use `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM` in place of `=` or `<>` and it will treat NULL like a value.

I used the following and it removed my empty strings without removing my NULLs

```
WHERE my_row IS DISTINCT FROM ''
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html

Comment: That is because when NULL is involved you are no longer looking at binary (Boolean) 2-state logic where results are always True, False. With nulls you are working tertiary or 3-state logic where the results are True, False, or Null. Any comparison operator applied against Null results in Null.